# Opencv and hive udf

Tags: opencv, hive, udf

Im trying to create hive udf, that include opencv function in it.
I am using netbeans java, and the function is working from the netbeans.

When I transfer the created jar to the hadoop and create the udf, i am getting
error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.opencv/core/Mat.
```

I think the error is on the `system.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME)`
Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: have you tried to add opencv jar in hive class path: hive --auxpath opencv-x.x.x.jar

Comment: The problem is that the opencv jar needs to have a link to dll file, when I define this dll location in netbeans its work but on the server as udf it doesn't